# Runtime error starting Service caused by ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, service

I am getting runtime error, trying to start a boot-time service.  Its failing but there is no hint I can see.  The intent is finding the Service but it doesn't get to onCreate or onStart.

```
public class ControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  /**
   * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(Context,Intent)
   */
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyApp.class);
    Log.d("rcvr", "Received intent:" + intent.getAction());
    context.startService(service);
  }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<manifest 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.company.package" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="9" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CELL_ID"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/mod_name" 
        android:name=".MyApp">

        <!-- We declare our service here -->
        <service 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/serv_name" 
            android:name=".MyApp" 
            android:process=":my_process">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.company.package.MY_INTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </service>
        <receiver 
            android:name=".ControlReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver 
            android:name=".BatteryHelper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The exception thrown

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.company.package.MyApp: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.package.MyApp cannot be cast to android.app.Application    
 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:529)    
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4442)     
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)     
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)     
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)     
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)     
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)    
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

**Update**
When I removed android:name=".MyApp" for the application from the manifest, the service started. Anyone know why?

Comment: I tried adding the following to the service in the manifest with no change: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Answer (score 0):

> when I removed android:name=".MyApp" for the application from the manifest, the service started. Anyone know why?

The reason for this is most likely the fact that your `MyApp` class does not extend `android.app.Application`.

As the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) says:

> `android:name`
>
> The fully qualified name of an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) subclass
>   implemented for the application. When the application process is
>   started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's
>   components.
>
> The subclass is optional; most applications won't need
>   one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the
>   base Application class.

Since subclassing `Application` is optional, removing `android:name=".MyApp"` allows your app to properly start because you're no longer trying to cast `MyApp` to `Application` which is exactly what your exception claims your app is trying to do.